# Using Solr with frequently updated data

Tags: search, solr

I have a site search I would like to implement using Solr. Unfortunately, I also have a lot of frequently updated dynamic data in my MySQL database from cron jobs, which I would also like to be searchable.

I would automatically assume that constantly updating records in Solr is not a good idea so is there a workable solution to give me the text-search power of Solr as well as being able to filter based on these frequently updated fields?

Comment: I've just found http://sphinxsearch.com/ which might satisfy my requirements.

Comment: Elasticsearch ( http://www.elasticsearch.org) is build from the ground up to support this. Backed by Lucene (like Solr) and an insanely fast growing community for support, although not quite as big as Solr's (yet). I've switched 1 year ago from Solr to ES and have never looked back since.

Comment: @Ryall - Sphinx is not half as powerful or flexible or extendable as Solr.. you made the right choice by going for solr. Don't shift to sphinx.

Comment: The thing is, in this particular case, I don't need anything beyond a basic text search. The reason I chose Solr was familiarity but it's good to know the information I learned here nonetheless - so thanks everyone. I have gone with Sphinx because it's exceedingly easy to set up, is lightweight, and meets all my requirements on this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this depends what "frequently" means and how long your tolerated Solr-lag is.

In my case, i update Solr twice every minute, which works fine.
..based on an MySql DB with some hundred updates a Minute.

In this situation it's important NOT to run an optimize on every Solr update/commit. Better run an optimize every n hoers.
So finally, all the new MySQL stuff will be visible in Solr with max. 30 sec. delay.

It depends on your situation if this is acceptable.

Comment: +1 Exactly, keep track of all that has changed and update the index (of the changed ones) once every N minutes/seconds. Even otherwise, i don't think solr's gonna choke unless you are doing more than 100s of updates every minute.