# How to index new data with Solr 4.0 when the database is updated?

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, nutch

I have a database populated with fetched and parsed web pages. Does Solr know automatically which of the columns are updated to index only the changes? Or should i make my own java code or something else (like conf. changes) to check if there are any changes?

Comment: why have you stored the pages in db ? you can have a direct integration of Nutch to Solr so that the Solr index is updated as soon as the Nutch finishes crawling.

Comment: Yes i know that, but when Nutch finishes with crawling does automatically Solr index only the updated data and if so how does Solr know to index only the new data?

Comment: Nutch maintains the data for new urls and updated urls which is stored as a separate segment after every crawling. This is then fed to Solr which would add if the url does not exist or update the record if url exists http://pascaldimassimo.com/2010/06/11/how-to-re-crawl-with-nutch/

Comment: So to resume: Solr automatically takes care of updating new data and we have to configure Nutch to re-crawl on particular time. Right?

Comment: you have to fire Nutch through some scheduler. Nutch should index the data and update the index segment which is then provided to Solr for Indexing which is the delta.

Comment: sure np. Just check the links and http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A4._Setup_Solr_for_search .it will give you more idea. You may need some job customization or some more it make it working perfectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Solr with frequently updated data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781129/using-solr-with-frequently-updated-data)